# Neo4J get N latest relationships per unique target node?

Tags: neo4j

With the following graph:

[image]

How can I write a query that would return N latest relationships by the unique target node?

For an example, this query: `MATCH (p)-[r:RATED_IN]->(s) WHERE id(p)={person} RETURN p,s,r ORDER BY r.measurementDate DESC LIMIT {N}` with N = 1 would return the latest relationship, whether it is RATED_IN Team Lead or Programming, but I would like to get N latest by each type. Of course, with N = 2, I would like the 2 latest measurements per skill node.

I would like the latest relationship by a person for Team Lead and the latest one for Programming.

How can I write such a query?

-- EDIT --

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE id(p)=175
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
 WITH {p} AS p
 MATCH (p)-[r:RATED_IN]->(s)
 RETURN DISTINCT s, r ORDER BY r.measurementDate DESC LIMIT 2',
 {p:p}) YIELD value
RETURN p,value.r AS r, value.s AS s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Cypher knowledge base article on [limiting MATCH results per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/), with a few different suggestions on how to accomplish this given current limitations. Using APOC's `apoc.cypher.run()` to perform a subquery with a RETURN using a LIMIT will do the trick, as it gets executed per row (thus the LIMIT is per row).

Note that for the upcoming Neo4j 4.0 release at the end of the year we're going to be getting some nice Cypher goodies that will make this significantly easier. Stay tuned as we reveal more details as we approach its release!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I am struggling to figure out how to write the APOC procedure correctly... I've put an EDIT in my original question of the query I have been trying out but I cannot figure it out, could you please give me advice? The `DISTINCT` seems incorrectly used, but I cannot figure out how I am supposed to use it...